# What do you call the point at which an individual water supply line enters a building?

Tags: word-choice

After an unsuccessful search for an English-language term meaning *the connection point from which water is taken from a main urban supply pipe to a house, facility, etc.*, I ended up here. Please note that I don't mean *a water meter*. With the term I am looking for, I would be able to say, for example, "this facility has three X's" (X being the term in question).
Update:
I want to know the English term for the point where the water supply company delivers a water tap to a house (company's responsibility ends) and then internal piping of the building is done from that tap. Depending on it size, a building might get several of these taps (which have to be paid for more). If we want to say my new construction will have 4 **water entries to the building**, what should we say? I want a term to put instead of the bold part of the sentence. Shall I use taps? Or there are better alternatives?

Comment: This will be a technical usage, possibly supplier-specific, and as such not really appropriate for a question on ELU. [Here](http://www.unitedutilities.com/pipes-what-am-i-responsible-for.aspx) is what United Utilities (UK) calls various bits and pieces.

Comment: Perhaps this is a question for http://diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: No. I don't want technical term. I want a general word for that. For example a real estate might say that a specific house has one electricity inlet, one phone line, and one water inlet(?)

Comment: *incoming* [water] supply line; the incoming.

Comment: In telecommunications, the connection point is called a [demarcation point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_point), or "demarc". I don't know if it applies to water service, though.

Comment: main water line entry point OR mains entry point

Answer (score 3):

This length of pipe between the mains and the home is often called the *supply line*. In the US, the name for the connection between the mains and the supply line is known as the *[corporation stop](http://www.free-ed.net/sweethaven/BldgConst/Plumbing01/lessonmain.asp?iNum=fra0204)*.  Sometimes the owner's responsibility ends at the *curb stop*.

Your question is somewhat unclear since you speak about "points" whereas the supply line is a *length* of pipe.  If you are interested in the boundaries, in a plumbing system they are usually  marked by so-called "stop valves" which allow flow in only one direction.

Comment: actually I mean a source of water entry to a building, be it a junction point or pipe,etc.

Comment: "Source" doesn't make it any clearer. But you probably mean the "supply line" or the "water service line" in the diagram shown in the link.

Comment: Probably tap is a better description. A tap that Water supply service delivers to a building, and then it is used to provide water for internal piping of the building.

Comment: In American English, "tap" in refers to the faucet. "Remember to turn off the tap".  It doesn't refer to the conduit between the mains and the dwelling. The water company doesn't deliver a "tap".

Comment: then, you don't agree with Hellion? What would you use instead?

Comment: The name for the pipe that brings water up to the house is the "water supply line" or the "water service line". It contains a stop valve called the "curb stop" that marks where the water company's responsibility ends and the homeowner's responsibility begins.

Comment: It's not that I disagree with Hellion. Your question is imprecise.

Answer (score 2):

The general term for making such a connection is *tapping* (see [m-w.com's "tap" entry, verb, sense 6a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tap)), and the connection itself can be referred to as a *tap* or a *tap point*.  This is a generic term, not specific to the water supply, so you need to specify what you're connected to, as in "this facility has three taps into the water mains".  Alternatively, you could say "this facility taps into the water mains at three points".

This can apply not only to the water mains but to any other utility that "flows" through some sort of pipe or conduit, such as sewage, natural gas, electricity, cable TV, etc.  In some cases (especially cable TV) there may be a connotation of making an illegal connection in order to gain access without payment, if it is not clear that the acting party was authorized to make the connection.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that "tap" can also mean "faucet" or "spigot", so you may need to make sure of your context; a real estate agent saying "this house has two water taps" is not necessarily saying the same thing as "this house has two taps into the water mains".

Comment: what do you mean by the last part? Do you mean that using tap for Cable TV might imply illegal access to it?

Comment: Depending on who says it, yes.  If your neighbor says "I set up a tap into the cable TV feed", he might be illegally acquiring access to extra content.  If your cable company technician says "I fixed a problem with your cable tap", that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the manifold per the plumber I just hired

Comment: A plumbing manifold distributes water from a central location to each fixture and is usually piped entirely inside a building. It does describe a type of "connection point where water is taken from a supply", but does not describe where "external" plumbing meets "internal". The homeowner very likely has responsibility for at least some of the plumbing upstream of the manifold.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a service connection.

> (21) "Service connection" means a piped connection from a water main for the purpose of conveying water to a building or onto premises for human use. A service connection begins: (A) at the point downstream of a service meter; or (B) for unmetered service, at the point of connection to the potable water supply system.

http://reports.oah.state.nc.us/ncac/title%2015a%20-%20environmental%20quality/chapter%2018%20-%20environmental%20health/subchapter%20c/15a%20ncac%2018c%20.0102.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the UK the pipe from the (water supply company's) *water main* to an individual householder's property line is called the *communication pipe* according to [this apparently authoritative source](https://www.waterregsuk.co.uk/information/legislation/glossary/supply_pipe/) (of information that is, not of water). The communication pipe becomes the *supply pipe* at the property line, together they form the *service pipe*.

Somewhat surprisingly, to this UK resident, the *external stop valve* (or *stop cock*) does not sit between the communication pipe and the supply pipe but in the communication pipe, outside the property line.

Incidentally, these are the terms used in the reference in Edwin Ashworth's first comment on the question. I thought I'd put them here where people can see them without having to follow a hyperlink. The explanation Edwin points us to clarifies that a communication pipe might be connected to a *common supply pipe* supplying water to a number of households.